# Expand image based on content

Tags: html, css

I have an image, it should expand as content expand inside it.Please suggest me better solution.

```css
.start-a-business-our-commitment-section {
  background-position: center left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.start-a-business-our-commitment-section .bottom-image {
  position: relative;
  height: 225px;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  font: 13px/1.5em "Effra",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
.start-a-business-our-commitment-section img {
  background-position: center left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 230px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.start-a-business-our-commitment-ribbon {
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
.start-a-business-our-commitment-ribbon-text {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  max-width: 970px;
}
.start-a-business-our-commitment-section .heading {
  font-family: "Nexa",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.start-a-business-our-commitment-section p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Effra",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="start-a-business-our-commitment-section">
  <div class="bottom-image">
    <img class="pic" src="http://qa-kentico-wv.wvhtest.com/getmedia/570851ce-5a5e-413a-95ad-e0d0e2460973/our-commitment-bg.jpg.aspx?width=2521&height=1716&ext=.jpg">
 <div class="start-a-business-our-commitment-ribbon">
   <div class="start-a-business-our-commitment-ribbon-text">
  <p class="heading"><!-- BEGIN ::startabusinessOurCommitmentHeading -->Our Commitment<!-- END ::startabusinessOurCommitmentHeading --></p>
  <p>From the moment you join our global family, you enter a circle of trust and transparency. We are committed to your success, and we are continuously developing marketing and training tools to help you on your journey. Without you, none of this would be possible. Your voice is important. As you explore the path you are on, we’re here to support you every step of the way.
  From the moment you join our global family, you enter a circle of trust and transparency. We are committed to your success, and we are continuously developing marketing and training tools to help you on your journey. Without you, none of this would be possible. Your voice is important. As you explore the path you are on, we’re here to support you every step of the way.
  From the moment you join our global family, you enter a circle of trust and transparency. We are committed to your success, and we are continuously developing marketing and training tools to help you on your journey. Without you, none of this would be possible. Your voice is important. As you explore the path you are on, we’re here to support you every step of the way
  From the moment you join our global family, you enter a circle of trust and transparency. We are committed to your success, and we are continuously developing marketing and training tools to help you on your journey. Without you, none of this would be possible. Your voice is important. As you explore the path you are on, we’re here to support you every step of the way
  </p>
   </div>
 </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `img` as a `background-image` for your `start-a-business-our-commitment-section`(that's a helluva class name) section.

Comment: Even i have tried by placing img as background-image but its not expanding as text changes dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Its working with `background-image`.Here is a sample snippet.You are using height with fixed `px` that is the problem.Use `height:auto` or `height:100%`

```css
div {
  background-image: url('http://qa-kentico-wv.wvhtest.com/getmedia/570851ce-5a5e-413a-95ad-e0d0e2460973/our-commitment-bg.jpg.aspx?width=2521&height=1716&ext=.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  From the moment you join our global family, you enter a circle of trust and transparency. We are committed to your success, and we are continuously developing marketing and training tools to help you on your journey. Without you, none of this would be
  possible. Your voice is important. As you explore the path you are on, we’re here to support you every step of the way. From the moment you join our global family, you enter a circle of trust and transparency. We are committed to your success, and we
  are continuously developing marketing and training tools to help you on your journey. Without you, none of this would be possible. Your voice is important. As you explore the path you are on, we’re here to support you every step of the way. From the
  moment you join our global family, you enter a circle of trust and transparency. We are committed to your success, and we are continuously developing marketing and training tools to help you on your journey. Without you, none of this would be possible.
  Your voice is important. As you explore the path you are on, we’re here to support you every step of the way From the moment you join our global familyery step of the way. From the moment you join our global family, you enter a circle of trust and transparency.
  We are committed to your success, and we are continuously developing marketing and training tools to help you on your journey. Without you, none of this would be possible. Your voice is important. As you explore the path you are on, we’re here to support
  you every step of the way From the moment you join our global family
</div>
```

Comment: image should display as per div content, image should come around content only.In your case image is displaying 100%(full).